# Raspberry PI RESTful services not accesable

Tags: python, rest, raspberry-pi, restful-url, webiopi

I'm trying to call the webiopi's RESTful webservices calls like

```
(IP)/GPIO/0/value/1
```

but always get the error like

```
Error response
Error code: 404
Message: 0/value/1 Not Found.
Error code explanation: 404 - Nothing matches the given URI.
```

while

```
 (http://IP) (my ip of raspberry pi through which i can access it from browser ie webiopi)
```

put that on browser go through all the web app all works fine

On the back end the web app sends the same calls as we can see in the console.

What could be the possible solution, are my files not in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Your files seem to be in the right place.
You can't **POST** using your browser's address bar or URL bar.
The error you are getting is related to a wrong **GET** format.

Look ...

These are **POST** to **SET** values (they won't work using address bar - you will get that error)

```
(IP)/GPIO/24/function/OUT
(IP)/GPIO/24/value/1
```

These are **GET** to **GET** values (they **WILL** work using address bar - give it a try)

```
(IP)/GPIO/24/function
(IP)/GPIO/24/value
```

So, how to **POST** using your browser (but not address bar)?

Using a REST Client (browser plugin - [POSTMAN](http://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) for example):

[image]

Are there other alternatives? Yes:

1 - Creating an HTML page with a FORM and a POST action button;

or

2 - Using RPi terminal console (via SSH, VNC, direct, UART, etc):

```
curl -X POST http://(IP)/GPIO/24/function/OUT
curl -X POST http://(IP)/GPIO/24/value/1
```

For those who don't know WebIOPi interface, after these REST commands, it will look like this:

[image]